# Problema con MySQL y Visual Studio [error al agregar a tabla] especificamente ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

El error surge en la linea 43 al tratar de insertar datos. Específicamente donde dice `int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` Aquí les dejo todo el código.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Column count doesn't match
>   value count at row 1'

```
    public bool Insertar(string nombre, string contraseña, string segundo_nombre, string apellido, string sexo, string Tipo_Documento, string Numero_Documento, string Fecha_Nacimiento, string Telefono, string Telefono_dos, string email, string email_dos)
    {
        conexion.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("insert into usuario values ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}', '{11}')", new string[] {nombre, contraseña, segundo_nombre, apellido, sexo, Tipo_Documento, Numero_Documento, Fecha_Nacimiento, Telefono, Telefono_dos, email, email_dos }), conexion);
        int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conexion.Close();

        if (filasafectadas > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Comment: Si, hice el conteo, verifique los signos, verifique los nombres. Y nada. Al ejecutar y ingresar los daos y darle insertar, se jode

Comment: Es la primera vez que lo hice, y lo hice al pie de la letra del video, y nada

Comment: si, todos son varchar(45) y (15)

Comment: Que deberia hacer, te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Osea, puse exactamente losmismos campos de las tablas, y sus nombres exactos

Comment: En cual método especifico es que te da el error?. Y si puedes mostrar la tabla de la base de datos para comparar los campos de la tabla con los que envías desde c#?

Comment: Mira, especificamente le estoy enviando 12, pero tiene 13. puesto que el ID esta automatico

Comment: No es lo que me dijiste mas arriba!!! a ver.. ordenemos todo. Agarra la pregunta, borra todo lo que no corresponda a ella (no sabemos cual es la linea 43), deja solo la parte importante, aclara el error, mostra la tabla y de paso, Aclara si el error no es que el parametro {0} no le faltan las comillas simples.

Comment: Agrega el error en la pregunta. Y mostra la tabla, asi podemos dilucidar el error. y fijate lo que te dije del parametro 0

Comment: insert into usuario values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}', '{11}') <--- proba con ese insert

Comment: ?asi como esta?

Comment: te marque un error varios comentarios antes.. y ahi te lo corregi

Comment: Recordad, Jatniel y @gbianchi, ir borrando los comentarios obsoletos :P  Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Deberías usar parámetros en el `insert`, NUNCA se concatena en el `string`, ademas cuando hay tantos parámetros en un método se debe definir una `class`

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string nombre {get;set;}
    public string contraseña {get;set;}
    public string segundo_nombre {get;set;}

    //resto
}
```

entonces tu codigo quedaria

```
public bool Insertar(Usuario usuario)
{
    conexion.Open();

    string query = @"insert into usuario (nombrecampo1, nombrecampo2, nombrecampo3, ....") 
                        values ( ?nombre, ?password, ?segundonombre, ...)


    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conexion);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", usuario.nombre);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?password", usuario.contraseña);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?segundonombre", usuario.segundo_nombre);


    int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conexion.Close();

    return filasafectadas > 0;
}
```

Como verás esta mucho mas prolijo y entendible para analizar

donde puse ... debes completar el resto

Comment: Excelente recomendaciones como buenas practicas en el desarrollo con ado.net y c#. creo que en ésta linea, iria asi: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(**query**, conexion);

Comment: Esta bellisimo.jpg